# Extraer texto entre dos palabras

Tags: linux, bash

Como dice el titulo quiero extraer el texto que hay entre dos palabras. Para ello se me ocurrio crear un sistema con el comando **sed** que me permitiese sustituir lo que buscaba para luego con **greep** y **cut** extraerlo. Pero el resultado a sido en todos los casos un fracaso absoluto, os pongo un poco en situación.

Tengo este texto con muchisimo codigo por encima y por debajo:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="imagens">
        <a href="http://sitio.php">
            <img src="https://image.jpg" alt="texto" width="100%" height="100%"/></a>
        <span class="imdb"><b><b class="icon-star"></b></b> 7.2</span>
    </div>
    <span class="text">texto</span>
    <span class="fecha">2016</span>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="imagens">
        <a href="http://sitio.php">
            <img src="https://image.jpg" alt="texto" width="100%" height="100%"/></a>
        <span class="imdb"><b><b class="icon-star"></b></b> 7.2</span>
    </div>
    <span class="text">texto</span>
    <span class="fecha">2015</span>
</div>
```

**EJ:**
Parametrizo estos dos textos "`<div class="item"><div class="imagens">`" y este "`</div>`" de tal manera que quedase un texto como este:

```
<a href="http://sitio.php">
        <img src="https://image.jpg" alt="texto" width="100%" height="100%"/></a>
    <span class="imdb"><b><b class="icon-star"></b></b> 7.2</span>
</div>
<span class="text">texto</span>
<span class="fecha">2016</span>
```

**EDITO**

La respuesta de [@Ivan Botero](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/46147/25508) creo que es la mas cercana a la solución del problema que tengo, pero sigo con el problema de que no consigo seleccionar el segundo `</div>` que tiene.

Y las etiquetas que no deben de salir son:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="imagens">
```

y el **segundo**:

```
</div>
```

Debido a que el primero esta en medio del codigo, justo detras de la etiqueta de cerrar **span**.
Alguna ayuda por favor?

Comment: Debes agregar tu codigo **mostrarnos tu esfuerzo, lo que has hecho** Aqui estamos para ayudarte no para hacerte la tarea

Comment: Tal y como indica @IvanBotero, muestra por favor qué has intentado. No poniendo un enlace sino añadiendo el código en sí. En cuanto a usar Bash, para esto es mejor utilizar un parseador de HTML.

Comment: Disculpen, pero he tratado de hacerlo con **sed** intentando reemplazar el texto del principio y del final, para crear marcas unicas y de esta manera poder agrupar el texto que quiero. Despues lo puedo unir en una unica linea y asi con un grep y un cut poder extraerlo y añadirlo en otro fichero, pero despues de muchas pruebas he visto que no conseguia nada, por lo que no he añadido ningun codigo de los que he probado ya que considero que ninguno a ofrecido algun tipo de aporte para esta pregunta

Comment: Sí se puede hacer con `sed` y expresiones regulares (si reabren la pregunta pongo una respuesta) sin embargo el requerimiento exacto que pides está un poco difícil pues hay varios cadenas de texto iguales `</div>`

Comment: @juan no se si caes en cuenta que el error te dice que "line is not defined" es decir no esta definida, si vas a tu linea 9 defines una variable llamada linea, pero accedes desde line, alli hay un error, deberia ser: `(linea for linea in fichero if not linea.startswith(inicio))`, por otro lado, rectifica el encoding que en python 2.7 es asi en la primera linea: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: Realice una prueba con esto _sed -n '/^<div class="item">/,/^<\/div>/p' archivo.html_ pero el texto que esperas esta repetido un par de veces :(

Comment: Version mejorada: sed -n '/^<div class="item">/,/^<\/div>/{p; /<\/div>/q}' archivo.html

Comment: @IvanBotero sobre [tu edición](http://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28138): poner el nombre de la etiqueta en el título no añade ningún valor, es mejor no hacerlo pues la etiqueta en sí ya da esta información. Por cierto, yo había eliminado la etiqueta Bash porque los intentos del autor se centran en Python.

Comment: @fedorqui No me habia percatado de ello, lo siento, ya lo corregiré

Comment: @IvanBotero no pasa nada, simplemente tenlo en cuenta para el futuro ;-)

Comment: @fedorqui Corregido, esperare a que pase la revision :-) Mientras, pueden probar el script que realice como respuesta, quiza haya alguna sugerencia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al final he conseguido obtener un código en **bash** para realizar el trabajo que necesitaba, gracias por ayudarme a todos!

Como dije en un buen principio con **sed** estaria genial obtenerlo, pero es imposible debido a que hay dos veces el texto de `</div>` y el sed creo que no puede trabajar con ello, mi solucion es la siguiente:

```
#!/bin/bash
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
encontrar=0
primera_fuera=0
while read texto ; do
    if [ $encontrar -eq 0 -a "$texto" == '<div class="item">' ]; then
        encontrar=1
    fi

    if [ $encontrar -eq 1 ] && [ "$texto" = '<div class="imagens">' ]; then
        encontrar=3
        primera_fuera=1
    fi

    if [ $encontrar -gt 2 ] && [ $primera_fuera -eq 0 ];then

        if [ "$texto" = '</div>' ];then
            echo -n ""
        else
            echo $texto
            #SALIDA del texto que buscamos
        fi

    else
        primera_fuera=$(($primera_fuera-1))
    fi

    if [  $encontrar -gt 1 ] && [ "$texto" = '</div>' ];then
        echo ""
        encontrar=$(($encontrar -1))
        if [ $encontrar -eq 1 ];then
            encontrar=0
        fi
    fi
done < index.html
```

Answer (score 2):

Saludo, he estado observando lo que requieres, basado en lo que dices (que se puede usar BASH), he hecho un script que espero, pueda ayudarte con tu problema.

### script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# Parametros
INICIO=$1
FINAL=$2
ARCHIVO=$3

# Escapamos INICIO y FINAL
E_INICIO="${INICIO/\//\\/}"
E_FINAL="${FINAL/\//\\/}"

# Expresion a buscar
EXPRESION="/^$E_INICIO/,/^$E_FINAL/{p;/$E_FINAL/q}"

sed -n "$EXPRESION" $ARCHIVO
```

Este toma tres parametros, la cadena de *inicio*, *final* y el *archivo*, basado en ellos realiza un *escape* de caracteres (Es decir cambia los / por /) para que se puedan usar en la expresion regular que se pasa posteriormente al comando *sed*.

Espero te sirva.

He aqui un ejemplo del funcionamiento:

### archivo.html

```
<div class="item">
<div class="imagens">
    <a href="http://sitio.php">
        <img src="https://image.jpg" alt="texto" width="100%" height="100%"/></a>
    <span class="imdb"><b><b class="icon-star"></b></b> 7.2</span>
</div>
<span class="text">texto</span>
<span class="fecha">2016</span>
</div>
<div class="item">
<div class="imagens">
    <a href="http://sitio.php">
        <img src="https://image.jpg" alt="texto" width="100%" height="100%"/></a>
    <span class="imdb"><b><b class="icon-star"></b></b> 7.2</span>
</div>
<span class="text">texto</span>
<span class="fecha">2015</span>
</div>
```

### Consola

```
bash script.sh '<div class="item">' '</div>' archivo.html
```

### Resultado

```
<div class="item">
<div class="imagens">
    <a href="http://sitio.php">
        <img src="https://image.jpg" alt="texto" width="100%" height="100%"/></a>
    <span class="imdb"><b><b class="icon-star"></b></b> 7.2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias! Pero como comento @Gepser hay 2 etiquetas de `</div>` que cierran y el problema estaba en ese punto, que el código queda cortado por la mitad, pero el resto esta bastante bien y seguro que a mucha gente le sirve. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

El error que te muestra

> SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file prueba.py on line 7,
>   but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html
>   for detail

por que tienes caracteres Non-ASCII en tu script (el que agarraste de la otra pregunta posee acentos ) Debes definir la codificación de caracteres que utilizara python para tratar el archivo: esto es para la version 2.7 y menores. ya que python 3 no es necesario.

```
# coding: utf-8
```

Comment: Gracias. Pero parece que no es el unico problema que tiene el codigo... Igualmente lo uso como ejemplo para un codigo en bash. Ya que todo mi programa lo he realizado en bash y me he encontrado con ese problema que no consigo solucionar...